# R - Use literal string parameters in R functions

Tags: r

How do I reference parameters that are literal strings ?

In the example below I want to get the min CONTACT_DATE in the dataframe

```
fx1  <- function(df1, pDate ) { 
  cat( as.Date( df1[ pDate] ) %>% min( na.rm = TRUE) );
}

# Print the Min CONTACT_DATE 
fx1 ( df_Del0 , "CONTACT_DATE");
```

Thanks for your help
Aubrey

tried different ways like

```
cat ( as.Date(df1[eval(parse(pDate)]) %>% min( na.rm = TRUE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `[[` instead of `[` to extract as a `vector` as `as.Date` or `min` works on `vector`s

```
fx1 <- function(df1, pDate) {
        min(as.Date(df1[[pDate]]), na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

The `%>%` is a magrittr chain.  Chaining can be done in `base R` with `|>` (from `R 4.1.0`)

```
fx1 <- function(df1, pDate) {
        df1[[pDate]] |>
         as.Date() |>
         min(na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

Also, `cat/print` just print the output into console and doesn't have a `return` value.  We can return the output for future use instead of just printing